# How to implement a faker into my go test?

Tags: unit-testing, go, faker

I am trying to learn Go and write my first test. I would like to figure out how to implement a faker to test CRUD on terraform.

I've figured out how to import faker and created the variables to use.

I tried to fmt.Println to see if it generates, but where do I see the Println if it's a test. It does not print when I do go test.

```
func testCheckTritonUserDelete(s *terraform.State) error {
    fmt.Println("INside testCheckTritonUserDelete")
    fmt.Println(fake.UserName())
    return nil
```

// this is the function in which I want to Println

Comment: Go suppresses the stdout of passing tests, otherwise a passing run would be incredibly noisy. Use `-v` to see the full output. Or just look at `go help test` and `go help testflag`.

Answer (score 1):

A test will say 'ok' if it has passed. A failing test will show the output. A quick way of making that happen is to add `t.Fail()` at the end of your Go test.

Comment: my test passes and says OK however I dont know where to see the PrintLn to see if its generating a username